# onPostExecute() doesn't start

Tags: java, android, json

I have a problem with some information downloaded from a DDBB. I recieve all the information, but I can't store it on my arrays because the onPostExecute() method doesn't starts. I put my code:

RequestRocodromo.java, is the class for making the request and recieve the information, on "results" variable I have all the information, but I can't storage it on the arrays of onPostExecute():

```
@Override
protected JSONObject doInBackground(String... params) 
{
    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(_url);

    String results = "NO OK";
    try 
    {       
        // Add your data
        /*List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(1);
        nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("mac", _mac ));
        httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));*/

        // Execute HTTP Post Request
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        response.getAllHeaders();
        response.getEntity();

        if(response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        {
            results = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
        }

        broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("correcto", results);
        broadcastIntent.setAction(ACTION_REQUEST_ROCODROMO);
        broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        _ctx.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }       
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ex.printStackTrace();       
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject jsonResponse) 
{
    super.onPostExecute(jsonResponse);

    List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>(); 
    ArrayList<String> rocodromoId = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> rocodromoArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> ciudadArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> comentarioArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    //Procesamos los resultados
    try
    {
        if(jsonResponse != null)
        {
            JSONArray jsonMainNode =jsonResponse.optJSONArray("edificios");

            int lengthJsonArr =jsonMainNode.length();
            for(int i=0; i<lengthJsonArr; i++)
            {
                JSONObject jsonChildNode = jsonMainNode.getJSONObject(i);
                rocodromoId.add(jsonChildNode.optString("id"));
                rocodromoArray.add(jsonChildNode.optString("nombre")); 
                ciudadArray.add(jsonChildNode.optString("ciudad")); 
                comentarioArray.add(jsonChildNode.optString("comentario")); 
                values.add(jsonChildNode.optString("nombre")); 
            }
        }

        String result[] = values.toArray(new String[values.size()]);

        broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("edificios", result);
        broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("id_rocodromo", rocodromoId);
        broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("rocodromoArray", rocodromoArray);
        broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("ciudadArray", ciudadArray);
        broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("comentarioArray", comentarioArray);
        broadcastIntent.setAction(ACTION_REQUEST_ROCODROMO);
        broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        _ctx.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        String result = "null";

        broadcastIntent = new Intent();
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("edificios", result);
        broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("id_rocodromo", rocodromoId);
        broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("rocodromoArray", rocodromoArray);
        broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("ciudadArray", ciudadArray);
        broadcastIntent.putStringArrayListExtra("comentarioArray", comentarioArray);
        broadcastIntent.setAction(ACTION_REQUEST_ROCODROMO);
        broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
        _ctx.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
    }
}
```

Rocodromo.java, here is where I start the execute method:

```
RequestRocodromo re = new RequestRocodromo(ctx, finalURL + "request=1");        

re.execute("");
```

Rocodromo.java, here is my broadcast, when I try to obtain the arraylist information I recieve a nullException, because my arraylist are null because it never starts the onPostExecute() method.

```
public class ReceptorBroadcast extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent intent)
    {
        if(RequestRocodromo.ACTION_REQUEST_ROCODROMO.equals(intent.getAction()))
        {
            idRocodromo = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("id_rocodromo"); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), idRocodromo.get(0).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            rocodromo = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("rocodromoArray"); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), rocodromo.get(0).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            ciudad = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("ciudadArray"); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), ciudad.get(0).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            comentario = intent.getStringArrayListExtra("comentarioArray"); 
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), comentario.get(0).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Can someone help my with that? Thanks! :)

Comment: Probably due to returning `return null;` from `doInBackground ` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change on doInBackGround return null to:

```
try {
    return new JSONObject(reusults); 
} catch (Throwable t) {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change you broadcast receiver call in your doInBackground().. as

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

          @Override
          public void run() {

          broadcastIntent = new Intent();
          broadcastIntent.putExtra("correcto", results);
          broadcastIntent.setAction(ACTION_REQUEST_ROCODROMO);
          broadcastIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT);
          _ctx.sendBroadcast(broadcastIntent);
        }
  });
```

and check null result in onPostExecute as..

```
if(null!=jsonResponse) // avoids null pointer;
```